# Ошибка NullPointerExceptiоn

Tags: java, sqlite

Почему данный код возвращает NullPointer, вроде бы все правильно сделал, в папке файл Users.db есть.

```
    public void FirstConnectionInsert(String nick) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + 
        plugin.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "Users.db");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO USERS (ID, NICK, KITS, BALANCE, 
        KILLS, DEATH) " +
                "VALUES (null, '"+ nick + "', 0, 0 , 0, 0 );";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() 
    );
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите stacktrace, пожалуйста

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CdC31A7n
(Лимит символов, поэтому залил на pastebin.)

Comment: Думаю, что ошибка при создании подключения. Проверьте отладчиком какую строку подключения передаете  в getConnection(...) и на какой строке падает.

Comment: Наверно файл лежит не в той папке где надо или у нему нет доступа.

Comment: Как вариант, нельзя вставить `null` в поле ID таблицы USERS, ибо ID это PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: null в ID ибо там стоит AUTO-INSCREMENT